# Вопрос по emmet в sublime text

Tags: sublime-text

В [этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyWPLShlfFc) человек на 2:37 мин:сек оборачивает кусочек кода при помощи <kbd>enter abbreviation</kbd>, не пойму как это сделать. Как?

В документации написано нажмите <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+A</kbd> и затем введите, например, <kbd>div</kbd> или <kbd>div.myclass</kbd>, выделенный текст обернется дивом. Но у меня по нажатию <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+A</kbd> ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это *Emmet: Wrap With Abbreviation*, по умолчанию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

[image: Скриншот]

— См. [список горячих клавиш `emmet-sublime`](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions)

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, что в Sublime Text 3 этот плагин имеет свойство сбоить и в нем отключается возможность обертывания кода по этому сочетанию клавиш. Помогает только переустановка плагина. Сталкивался с этим уже с десяток раз.

Comment: @VenZell это не относится непосредственно к вопросу, это скорее обсуждение предмета вопроса. Склонен считать, что в ответе этому не место :)

Comment: Что ж, пусть хотя бы комментом повисит

Comment: @D-side да, так работает, пасиб. Плагин установлен с нуля сегодня.